# If $M$ is a subspace of a Hilbert space, then $(M^\bot)^\bot$ is the closure of $M$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

I have found a few questions similar to this one, namely [If $M$ is a closed subspace of an Hilbert space $H$, then $M^{\perp\perp}=M$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989671/if-m-is-a-closed-subspace-of-an-hilbert-space-h-then-m-perp-perp-m), but I am not assuming that $M$ is closed, so I believe this warrants a separate question. I know that I would like to use the orthogonal composition theorem, but I am not sure how to arrive there. Any hints for what proof approach I should take are appreciated. Is it as simple as a double inclusion proof?

Comment: If $x\perp M$, then $x\perp \overline{M}$ (closure) because of the continuity of the inner product. So $M^{\perp}=\overline{M}^{\perp}$. Then $\overline{M}=\overline{M}^{\perp\perp}=M^{\perp\perp}$.

Comment: @Sharkos I'm not sure if this is a duplicate or not.. is there a difference between $\text{span}(A)$ and $M$?