# Show that $\overline{V}=(V^{\bot})^{\bot}$ in Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $(\mathcal{H},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a Hilbert space and let $U$ denote a *closed* subspace of $\mathcal{H}$. Show that:
$$U=(U^{\bot})^{\bot}$$

Afterwards, then show for a subspace $V$ of $\mathcal{H}$ that:

$$\overline{V}=(V^{\bot})^{\bot}$$

where $\overline{V}$ denotes the closure of $V$.

---

**My thoughts:** So I don't know quite how to approach this. I've thought about show both inclusions but I don't see a good way to do so for the first equality. Also for the second part I know the closure of a set is closed however V itself is not closed so the second doesn't just follow immediately from the first. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1989671/81360) for the more difficult direction

Comment: I would encourage you to try to prove the inclusion $U \subset U^{\perp \perp}$ on your own.  Ultimately the proof comes down to characterizing $U^{\perp \perp}$, then showing that every $u \in U$ satisfies this characterization.

Comment: Thank you, this helped to show that $U=(U^{\bot})^{\bot}$. However I don't see how the same argument works for $\overline{V}$ though. I can only use orthogonal decomposition if $V$ itself is closed, right? The only things that comes to mind is using sequences but maybe I am overlooking something easier :)

Comment: It is easy to show that $V \subset V^{\perp \perp}$.  For the other direction, note that $V^\perp = (\bar V)^\perp$

Comment: Wouldn't I have to show that $\overline{V} \subseteq V^{\bot \bot}$? And why is that note true?

Comment: Once you have established that $(\bar V)^{\perp} = V^{\perp}$, it follows that $(\bar V)^{\perp \perp} = V^{\perp \perp}$, which is to say that $\bar V = V^{\perp \perp}$.  Try to figure out the note for yourself; it comes down to the definition of the closure.